# How do we mock in this kind of situation?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Let's put up this scenario

```
# This code lives in lolcat-web/lolapps/lolburger/burger.py
import os
from helper.lib import price

def i_haz_cheezeburger(Burger, user):

    kings_burgers = []
    queens_burgers = []
    address = os.path.join(user.hometown, burger_king_addr)
    burger_menu = Burger.menu()
    for burger in burger_menu:
       if burger == 'King':

            kings_burgers.append({
                    'name': burger, 
                    'price': price(burger)
                   })
       else:
            queens_burgers.append(...)

    return (kings_burgers, queens_burgers)
```

I want to test whether the function `i_haz_cheezeburger` will return a tuple, with correct values in it. It depends on a few things (simplification):  `os`, `helper.lib.price`, `Burger`, and `user` (User class)

Since I am fairly new to `mock` by Michael Foord, here is my newbie attempt:

**edit** looks wrong because `joiner` and `price` doesn't seem to be used anywhere?

```
def test_01(unittest.TestCase):
   with patch('os.path.join') as joiner:
      with patch('lolcat-web.lolapps.lolburger.burger.price') as price: 
          mock_user = MagicMock(name='user', spec=client.auth.User)
          mock_user.hometown = 'New-York'
          mock_burger = MagicMock(name='burger', spec=lolcat-web.lolapps.lolburger.Burger)
          mock_burger.menu = [ '....sets up a list of samples .....' ]

          # now call the function
          response = i_get_cheezeburger(mock_burger, mock_user)
   # now we do some assertions.....
```

This is like writing fixtures. What if the method `i_haz_cheezeburger` has a few more dependencies. Of course I can refactor them out and create a few more wrapper / helper functions. But the problem is, or ***at least***  the confusion is:
    I want to test my output. I don't want to know "oh there is no mispell / unbound assignment because it passed with a per-defined return value" But setting up the fixtures (or return values for things like `Burger.menu`) doesn't sound right.

What's the proper way of dealing this kind of issue? Please correct my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

Don't mock out the *standard library* - if there's a problem with the standard library, you have bigger problems (not to mention you're almost certainly not integration-testing the standard library, so mocking it out is just hiding potential failures).

If the output of the function depends on the return value of `Burger.menu()`, then you need to set up a return value for `Burger.menu()`'s mock version if you want to test return values. That is the right thing to do. You provide mock inputs that are controlled versions of real-world input, and thus you expect a specific output given those controlled inputs. Using `mock` doesn't magically remove *all* actual realistic data from the equation.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it always a good choice to refactor most of the dependencies? Should I write unittests for each of those newly refactored methods?